# Dialogflow Bearer Token Analysis

Tags: dialogflow-es

How to I get a bearer token for a Dialogflow v2beta1 API call?

I want to integrate Dialogflow APIs so now I can't even test APIs in postman without bearer token. For testing I have generated API Key for my agent in GCP project but I didn't found any solution for getting bearer token.

```
POST https://dialogflow.googleapis.com/v2beta1/[PARENT]/intents?key=[YOUR_API_KEY] HTTP/1.1
```

---

```
Authorization: Bearer [YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN] Accept: application/json Content-Type: application/json
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess you already have a `Service Account` with proper permissions to project/product/resource. If no, you can find a guide on how to create it in [Creating and managing service accounts](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/creating-managing-service-accounts).

Regarding `Bearer Token` you should read about it in [Authenticating as a service account](https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/production#cloud-console).

If you have a `Service Account` with proper access and `key.json` you can use `Bearer token`.
In `GCP` console you can print default token using command:

```
### for default SA
$ gcloud auth application-default print-access-token

### for other SA
$ gcloud auth print-access-token SA_NAME@PROJECT_ID.iam.gserviceaccount.com
```

More details can be found in [this docs](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/auth/application-default/print-access-token).

Request for default `SA` should looks like this:

```
 curl -X POST /v2beta1/{parent=projects/*}/agent:train \
 -H "Authorization: Bearer $(gcloud auth application-default print-access-token)"
```

For specific one time request you should use below example:

```
  curl -X POST /v2beta1/{parent=projects/*}/agent:train \
 -H "Authorization: Bearer $(gcloud auth print-access-token <YourSAaccount>)"
```

SA account might looks like: `<SAname>@<projectID>.iam.gserviceaccount.com`

**Please keep in mind that this SA must be active.** You can do it using command to activate SA:

```
$ gcloud auth activate-service-account SA_NAME@PROJECT_ID.iam.gserviceaccount.com --key-file=/path/to/SAkey/key.json

###or using just key
$ gcloud auth activate-service-account --key-file=/path/to/SAkey/key.json
```

And command for listing active `SA` is:

```
$ gcloud auth list
```

I chose a random POST from [Dialogflow API](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/es/docs/reference/rest/v2beta1-overview).